# How to apply partial migration from code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Let's say I have 3 migrations in total: A, B and C. All migrations are built in code and executed from code (C# I mean).

I would like to apply all migrations up to given level (say B), give me back control, so I could do whatever I like outside the scope of EF/migrations/etc. When I am done with my own stuff, then execute full migration (so in this case it would mean C).

I know how to perform full migration from code :-), but how to tell EF to migrate up to given level?

Executing everything from the code (C#) is **crucial** here -- SQL scripts, or running external tools are no-go for me.

*For curious minds: use case -- I would like to prepare tests for the last migration in between.*

Comment: when updating your database you can add a -migration [migrationName] to update your database to a specific migration, but i guess the issue is that you already applied your migration and dont want to roll back?

Comment: @JochemVanHespen, I can rollback, or delete database, it is test environment, this is not a problem. However I am asking about code (C#), and I sense you have external tool (ef) in mind. Maybe I would have to run it from code as external program, but I will leave this as last resort solution. Thank you for reminding about it! :-)

Comment: You can comment your C# migration code to apply modifications that you need

Comment: @StepUp, true, but this is tiresome quickly. You comment out migration, compile, run part X of the program, uncomment, make program run Y part, ah, I have a bug in migration, ok, comment it back, rerun... I hope you see the amount of work with just commenting and uncommenting the code.

Comment: so maybe you can create another custom migration file with desired code and apply this migration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the EF-Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update) you should be able to run:

`dotnet ef database update Migration_Name`

To update the database up to a certain migration.

Running from code is a bit different. You could use `context.Database.Migrate()` to apply all pending migrations. Looking at the source code for this method we can see that is uses the underlying `IMigrate` service. I suppose you could try something like this:

`_context.Database.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate("Migration_Name");`

Which should be the same as the cli command i mentioned earlier. I currently have no quick way to test this, so it might not work.